# mysql triple join query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have tables shown below:

```
    users table
user_id user_email user_name
   1      a@a.com     a
   2      b@b.com     b
   3      c@c.com     c

    bookmarks table
bookmark_id  user_id      bookmark_url
    1           1        http://aaa.com
    2           3        http://bbb.com
    3           3        http://ccc.com
    4           3        http://ddd.com

    comments table
comment_id   user_id       content
    1           2          'hello'
    2           2          'hello2'
```

What I want to get is like this :

```
user_id  user_email  user_name bookmarksCount commentsCount
   1       a@a.com       a           1              0
   2       b@b.com       b           0              2
   3       c@c.com       c           3              0
```

From above, each `xxx_id` is auto incremented sequence id.

I think to get above result, I have to join these 3 tables.But, if there is no match `user_id` in bookmarks and comments table, they can't be joined. But I have to get result with `0` if there is no match.

Is it possible to join these tables to get result even though there is no match column?

Comment: difficult to do with joins (even left joins) because you want two separate counts in the same query, so effectively two separate aggregate functions. Separate queries / sub-queries as suggested  below is a decent solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use correlated subqueries:

```
select u.*,
       (select count(*) from bookmarks bm where bm.user_id = u.user_id
       ) as cnt_bookmarks,
       (select count(*) from comments c where c.user_id = u.user_id
       ) as cnt_comments
from users u;
```

If you attempt to do this using `join`, you will have problems, because you will generate a Cartesian product of bookmarks and comments for each user.  In addition, doing the aggregation after the join is likely to incur performance problems, because the data for the aggregation will be larger than necessary.

For this query, indexes on `bookmarks(user_id)` and `comments(user_id)` should provide very good performance.